# Tests in the repo - virtserver

Tags: xero-api

I am exploring the xero java sdk on the github.  I am examining the tests in the com.veersoft.api.client.  Many tests have the following

```
new ApiClient("https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/Xero/accounting/2.0.0",null,null,null);
```

What is that 'virtserver' url in the above api?

Answer (score 0):

The virtserver is a virtual server on swaggerhub where we have our OpenAPI spec documents.  We've mocked up API responses for endpoints and call those to test the models in the Java SDK.

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Xero/accounting/2.0.0